# pass array and object to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass both $data and $object when loading view_nav

```
 public function home(){
        $this->load->model('get_company_model');
        $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
        $data['results'] = $this->get_company_model->get_All();
        $object['site2']=$this; 
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $this->load->view('view_nav');
        $this->load->view('view_content');
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }
```

here I need to pass $data[results] and object of the current controller, how can I do this

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass two variables, but you can combine them into one in hundreds of ways. For example:

```
$data['site2'] = $object['site2']; // available as $site2 in the view
```

or

```
$data['object'] = $object; // available as $object['site2'] in the view
```

etc...

And then just add `$data` to the view:

```
$this->load->view('view_nav', $data);
```

Comment: here I need to pass $data[results] and object of the current controller, how can I do this

Comment: You can pass whatever you want into an array and then pass that array to the view. In this case, you'll have $data['results'] and $data['controller_object'] (assign the actual object to it), and just pass it to the view, like my answer says.

Answer (score 0):

If developer wants to get all categories from database into a variable of controller and wants to transfer this resultant array to the associate view, then he/she can follows the following process as well:-

```
$data = array();
$this->load->model('dbmodel');
$data['item'] = $this->dbmodel->getData('*','catagory',array());
$this->load->view('listing_view', $data);
```